# How do i send a json object property back to NODE by clicking a list item?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

i've rendered a JSON object ("data") to an EJS view.
The ".name" property gets displayed via. the forEach method:

```
<ul>
    <% data.forEach(function(itterator) { %>
        <a href="/selection"  onclick="submitfunc()"<li><%= itterator.name%></li</a>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

When the respective .name property is clicked, i want to send a corresponding "uri" property that belongs to the same JSON object to a route named "/selection".

How should one go about doing this? am i on the right track?

Comment: pass your property in your` submitfunc()` and then in submitfunc you should post the value to Node API

Comment: This is massively too broad for StackOverflow. You need to learn how to bind event handlers properly, how to identify the element that triggered the event handler, how to read data from the DOM, and how to use Ajax.